# Would it be possible to use a GSM without a SIM card?

Tags: microcontroller, integrated-circuit, gsm, sim, data-storage

I would like to reduce the footprint of my PCB (a simple IOT GSM impl.). Given a common GSM such as SIM800/868/900l etc. Would it be possible to completely replace the footprint of a SIM card holder (which is larger than the GSM/IC) by copying the data held on the SIM card initially to a global flash chip or suitable substitution thereof for later use (without the SIM card). Nothing seems obviously wrong with this approach though I thought I would double check:

[image]

where the sim1 and sim2 respectively represent the DATA (SIMDATA) pads of the sim 1 and 2 and the ic and gsm communicate via UART/GPIO.

[image]

Would there be anything initially wrong with following this trajectory or
any conceivable misnomer therein?

Thanks

Comment: You mean, something like an [eSIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESIM) ?

Comment: The Sim has crypto to protect the service providers data. As Finbarr suggests, an eSim might be appropriate, but not all providers support it. Its a bit bleeding edge at the moment.